# Custom Dialog Component Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Im trying to create a custom dialog component based on the v-dialog from vuetify framework.

```
<template>
    <v-dialog
      v-model="localDialog"
      max-width="290"
    >
      <v-card
      :color="localColor"
      >
        <v-card-title style="color:white;;" ><v-icon class="pr-2" color="white">{{localIcon}}</v-icon> {{localTitle}}</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text style="color:white; padding-top:5px;">
          {{message}}
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn
            color="white"
            text
            @click="localDialog = false"
          >
            OK
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    mounted(){
      this.initDialog();
    },
    props:[
      'type','message','dialog'
    ],
    data () {
      return {
        localDialog:this.dialog,
        localTitle:'Response',
        localColor:'red',
        localIcon:'mdi-alert-circle-outline'
      }
    },
    methods:{
      "initDialog": function () { console.log(this.dialog);
        switch (this.type) {
          case 'success':
            this.localIcon = "mdi-check-circle";
            this.localColor ="green";
            this.localTitle ="Operation Successful";
            break;
          case 'info':
            this.localIcon = "mdi-check-circle";
            this.localColor ="orange";
            this.localTitle ="Information";
             break;
          case 'error':
            this.localIcon = "mdi-alert-outline";
            this.localColor ="red";
            this.localTitle ="Error Occurred";
             break;
          default:
            this.localIcon = "mdi-alert-circle-outline";
            this.localColor ="blue";
            this.localTitle ="Information";
             break;
        }
      },
    } 
}
</script>
```

I understand how props work but i am having some difficulties toggling its status in the parent. Ideally what im trying to achieve is after an api call, i would like to display the dialog, not your normal "onClick" usage. But nothing happens after the api call.

In the parent

```
<dialog-message-component 
              :type=resultDialogType
              :message=resultDialogMessage
              :dialog=resultDialog
            />
    </v-dialog>
```

API Call

```
      Vue.axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/events/store",
        {
          title: this.title,

        }
        ).then((response) => {
            var parsedobj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));
            console.log(parsedobj);
            this.overlay=false;
            this.resultDialogMessage=parsedobj.message;
            this.resultDialogType="info";
            this.resultDialog=true;
            }) ;
```

What am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that data uses the value of passed properties as its INITIAL value. Any changes made to props afterwards are not passed to data, so it follow the concept of data() as local component memory, which can be manipulated locally, and props as external properties, which technically does not belong to the component, and shouldn't be mutated in the child component.

The simplest solution, is to create a watcher for the prop, and change local data on prop change.

```
watch: {
   dialog(val){
     this.localDialog = val
   }
}
```

Edited:

For passing the changed prop to the parent you use events:

Child:

```
<v-dialog @input="$emit('update:dialog', localDialog)">
...
</v-dialog>
```

Parent:

```
<dialog-message-component 
    :type=resultDialogType
    :message=resultDialogMessage
    :dialog.sync="resultDialog" // The equivalent of :dialog="resultDialog" @update:dialog='resultDialog = $event'
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, i've marked this as the answer, although how do i make the binding two-ways, i.e. when i click "OK" on my dialog and set the value to false in the child, how do i notify the parent of this change ? Sorry im a noob at this

Comment: Im aware that i can simply bind to "dialog" in the child but when i do that, i get the "Avoid mutating prop" error

Comment: Avoid two-way binding to props, since it mutates them directly. Use events to send changed prop value back to parent. See the updated answer.

Comment: Your updated answer works, but only for the first api request. If i close the dialog and make the request again, the dialog does not come up again

Comment: Ok i got it to work by putting the "$emit('update:dialog', localDialog)" in a closeDialog method which then notifies the parent ! Thanks for your help